@Cacheable vs @CachePut
User information can only be modified on the web, and can only be viewed on mobile.
However, data modified on the web using @Cacheable in EmpServiceImpl viewed on mobile is not updated directly on mobile.

In this case, is it better to delete @Cacheable or modify it with @CachePut?
I can't think of any other way, so I'd like to know how to solve it.

I wonder if I can just use @CachePut without @Cacheable.


Solution for how to handle @Cacheable

How many instances will your service be deployed to? If you use Cache in Spring, the request must be sent to the same instance in order to see the cached data. I think you should use a cache database like Redis or Memcached to share cached data across multiple instances.
EDIT:
@Cacheable will save the data only when it does not exist.
@CachePut will always update the data, even if it did not change.
So if you only have 1 instance for your service. Use CachePut in your update method
